# Bootstrap tool tip doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

Hello I read everything about the tooltips and it's JS.

1. bootstrap never included the download for bootstrap-tooltip.js, therefore I just linked bootstrap.js file.

my javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('.link').tooltip()
</script>
```

My HTML

```
<a href="#" class="link" data-original-title="first tooltip">Hover me for a tooltip</a>!
```

I tried moving the js to footer, under the div, to head, to top, and it doesn't work.. the javascript doesn't even start. it doesn't even show the default tooltip.

My page: http://justxp.plutohost.net/jonydesigns/tos.php

My whole tos.php page:
http://pastebin.com/qSe9NES7

Could someone please find out why doesn't the tooltip show up? I have included the bootstrap css too, the whole website is build with it actually.

Thanks!

Comment: You have `Uncaught TypeError` in *blogger.js* on line 12. Besides this is Twitter's script, it seems you haven't applied it correctly.

Comment: Fixed and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check your javascript errors.  twitterCallback2 is undefined.

Comment: I removed the errors mate. there are 0 errors in the console for that page now.

Comment: There's not a single reference to a tooltip in your source code at the moment--if you're changing things around, you should make a static demo for those of us trying to help you out...

Answer (score 4):

1: You're not linking the required `bootstrap-tooltip.js` anywhere. (At least I can't find it in your code.)

2: Your JavaScript code should be surrounded by`$(document).ready( ... )`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').tooltip();
});
```

Comment: Yet no error pops up when calling `$("#element").tooltip();` so it must be in the regular bootstrap file (or another plugin is doing this). ***Edit:*** Upon further investigation his [bootstrap.js](http://justxp.plutohost.net/jonydesigns/js/bootstrap.min.js) does include a lot of references to the `tooltip` function, so it's probably included.

Comment: tooltip function is included inside bootstrap.js  and it still doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

The fix for this issue is defined in the [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips):

> For performance reasons, the tooltip and popover data-apis are opt in,
>   meaning you must initialize them yourself.

However, this description I found to be quite vague and should have included an example.  Tooltips need to be "initialized".  In this case you can do this on document ready:

**jQuery**

```
$('.link').tooltip();
```

Then the **markup** you provided will display the tooltip on mouseover.

`<a href="#" class="link" data-original-title="first tooltip">Hover me for a tooltip</a>!`

Also note that bootstrap.js does include bootstrap-tooltip.js.  To see this open bootstrap.js and look for:

```
/* ===========================================================
 * bootstrap-tooltip.js v2.3.1
 * http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips
 * Inspired by the original jQuery.tipsy by Jason Frame
```

---

On a related note, "initialization" is also required for popovers.  E.G.

**Markup**

```
<a id="somePopoverId" href="#" rel="popover" class="btn btn-large btn-danger" data-content="Hello world!" title="" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="A whatever" data-container="body">Popover</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("a[rel='popover']").popover({
                placement: "top",
                trigger: "hover"
            });
```

Or more simply...

```
 $("#somePopoverId").popover({
                placement: "top",
                trigger: "hover"
            });
```